# code working if i put a string like s=1234567891 but if if i have a text file "yesno.txt" where i have data , having error

Tags: python, regex

My code is perfectly working if I have a string in the code itself like:

```
"s= my number is 1234567891"
```

But when I have this same text in my text file (yesno.txt), I am facing an error:

```
import re

def getphonenumber(s):
   phonenumberregex=re.compile(r'\+\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d|\d\d\d\d+-\d\d\d\d\d\d\d|\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d')
   matchobject = phonenumberregex.findall(s)
   #print("mobile number -",matchobject.group())  .....use this for printing
   if matchobject:
       return matchobject
   else:
       return None

s = open("yesno.txt","r")     
print(getphonenumber(s))
```

```py
File "C:/Users/G0002944/.spyder-py3/tryy1.py", line 12, in getphonenumber
    matchobject = phonenumberregex.findall(s)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Additionally, I want to transfer that data into the database.
Need help since I am new to python, thanks in advance.

Comment: `s` is a file object. So you have to call `read` method to get its contents. ie,`phonenumberregex.findall(s.read())`??